# How to change the array based on index in nested object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have a nested array object , key `value` array,

based on index, replace the value with content parameter

How to change the array value based on the index value in javascript

```
function changeValue(i,content){
 var result = obj.map(e=>{
     ...e,
     value: value[content]
  })

}

var obj=[
  {id:0, value:["SG","10","img"]}
]

Expected Output:
this.changeValue(1,"40");
[
 {id:0, value:["SG","40","img"]}
]

this.changeValue(0,"TH")
[
 {id:0, value:["TH","10","img"]}
]
```

Comment: `obj` is the only one element array?

Comment: the first map shouldn't even work since it contains a syntax error, unless you wrap an object into brackets `()` it will be considered body of a functon and not a return value

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value by changing the index directly.

```js
var obj = [
  { id: 0, value: ["SG","10","img"] }
];

function changeValue(i, content){
  var result = obj.map(e => {
    const value = [...e.value];
    value[i] = content;
    return { ...e, value };
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(changeValue(1,"40"));
console.log(changeValue(0,"TH"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take `object.assign` to an array with the array and an object as values.

```js
function changeValue(i, content) {
    return obj.map(e => ({
        ...e,
        value: Object.assign([], e.value, { [i]: content })
    }));
}

var obj = [{ id:0, value: ["SG", "10", "img"] }];

console.log(changeValue(1, "40")); // [{ id: 0, value: ["SG", "40", "img"] }]
console.log(changeValue(0, "TH")); // [{ id: 0, value: ["TH", "10"," img"] }]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```